# pytorch: RuntimeError: bool value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous

Tags: runtime-error, pytorch

it works with

```
x[x >= 0.2] = 1
x[x < 0.2] = 0
```

`x` is a tensor here.

but when i am trying to use

```
x[x > 0 and x < 1] = 1
```

it reports: `RuntimeError: bool value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous` ?

dose anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

Just a syntax thing.

```
x = torch.randn((1,3,20,20))
x[(x > 0) & (x < 1)] = 1
```